# Python one line for loop input

Tags: python, input

I don't know how to get input depending on user choice. I.e. 'How many numbers you want to enter?' if answers 5, then my array has 5 spaces for 5 integers in one line separated by space.

```
num = []
x = int(input())
for i in range(1, x+1):
    num.append(input())
```

Upper code works, however inputs are split by enter (next line). I.e.:

```
2
145
1278
```

I want to get:

```
2
145 1278
```

I would be grateful for some help.

EDIT:

```
x = int(input())
while True:
    attempt = input()
    try:
        num = [int(val) for val in attempt.split(" ")]
        if len(num)== x:
            break
        else:
            print('Error')
    except:
        print('Error')
```

This seems to work. But why I'm getting "Memory limit exceeded" error?

EDIT:
Whichever method I use, I get the same problem.

```
x = int(input())
y = input()
numbers_list = y.split(" ")[:x]
array = list(map(int, numbers_list))
print(max(array)-min(array)-x+1)
```

or

```
x = int(input())
while True:
    attempt = input()
    try:
        num = [int(val) for val in attempt.split(" ")]
        if len(num)== x:
            break
        else:
            print('Error')
    except:
        print('Error')

array = list(map(int, num))
print(max(array)-min(array)-x+1)
```

or

```
z = int(input())
array = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(max(array)-min(array)-z+1)
```

Comment: You can not prevent user to enter 5 number split by space. because after pressing enter the values receives in `input()` in your python code. you can only choose the first 5. is it ok ?

Comment: You cant limit the user entering more than the specified number, you might want to rethink on how you want to structure your input.

Comment: Ok, so explain to me how you escape out of the while loop. Is there ANY condition where it ends en continues to the end of the script?

Comment: I could not tell you why, as you did not provide the line of my code where this error occurs nor the input string you used. I can't see a reason why this code should exceed your memory limit, if the string you put in is small. If this happens with all code provided, the error is maybe in another part of your code.

Comment: It's all code provided. This exercise is going to be corrected by the bot. It is programmed to enter number of inputs in the first line, and in the next line it enters x integers separated by space. For array = list(map(int, input().split())) or num = [int(x) for x in input().split()] I'm getting "memory limit exceeded".

Comment: If the for loop yields a memory error, then input the bot i making is maybe to large. Try getting `len(attempt)` on my code in the line below of `attempt = input()` to see how big of an input the bot is making

Comment: I don't have the access to data what numbers is the bot testing.

Comment: Does this error occur when you are testing the code provided in a normal shell without any bot running? If no, the answer solves your question. Helping you with the error is quite difficult, as we have no information on what the bot is doing. If you continue having problems with this bot, and dont find an answer after searching, feel free to file a question regarding this error.

Comment: I don't want to make any bold assumptions; but unless the code tells you to "ensure the number of input entered is the same as the first integer", then you can ignore the first integer. (Most challenges/exercises on CodeChef, HackerRank, etc. have something similar to this, they're primarily meant for other languages such as C to provide a bound for a loop that will terminate.) If possible, include a link to the exercise, the input given, and the output expected. A lot of answers provided here fail to work partly due to insufficient information and context surrounding the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to input the numbers in one line, here is a possible solution. The user has to split the numbers just like you did in your example. If the input format is wrong (e.g. "21 asd 1234") or the number does not match the given length, the user has to enter the values again, until a valid input is made.

```
x = int(input("How many numbers you want to enter?"))
while True:
    attempt = input("Input the numbers seperated with one space")
    try:
        num = [int(val) for val in attempt.split(" ")]
        if len(num)==x:
            print(num)
            break
        else:
            print("You have to enter exactly %s numbers! Try again"%x)
    except:
        print("The given input does not match the format! Try again")
```

Comment: This solution quite works. Please check my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be something like this:

```
input_list = []

x = int(input("How many numbers do you want to store? "))

for inputs in range(x):
    input_number = inputs + 1
    input_list.append(int(input(f"Please enter number {input_number}: ")))

print(f"Your numbers are {input_list}")
```

Is there a reason you want the input to be on one line only? Because you can only limit how many numbers you store (or print) that way, not how many the user inputs. The user can just keep typing.

Comment: There is a specific reason. This exercise is going to be corrected by the bot. It is programmed to enter number of inputs in the first line, and in the next line it enters x integers separated by space. For array = list(map(int, input().split())) or num = [int(x) for x in input().split()] I'm getting "memory limit exceeded".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this without needing `x`:

```
num = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbers to be entered on one line, with just spaces, you can do the following:

```
x = int(input("How many numbers do you want to store? "))
y = input(f"Please enter numbers seperated by a space: ")
numbers_list = y.split(" ")[:x]
print(f"We have a list of {len(numbers_list)} numbers: {numbers_list}")
```

Even if someone enters more than the amount of promised numbers, it returns the promised amount.

Output:

```
How many numbers do you want to store? 4
Please enter numbers seperated by a space: 1 4 6 7
We have a list of 4 numbers: ['1', '4', '6', '7']
```

Comment: I like your solution, but I get error described in the edited post. =(

Comment: Then there's probably a problem on the bot you're entering it into. This should in no way use too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
x = int(input())
num = [] # List declared here
while True:
    try:
        # attempt moved inside while
        # in case input is in next line, the next line
        # will be read in next iteration of loop.
        attempt = input() 

        # get values in current line
        temp = [int(val) for val in attempt.split(" ")]

        num = num + temp
        if len(num) == x:
            break
    except:
        print('Error2')
```

Maybe the bot was passing integers with newline instead of spaces, in which case the while loop will never terminate (assuming your bot continuously sends data) because every time, it will just re-write num.

Note - this code will work for both space as well as newline separated inputs